# SQL Select foo if all match condition, return foo

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

- Long buildup prob simple answer...

I know this is going to require a subquery of some kind...

But I am joining 3 tables and trying to get an output...

> `table one 'Status'
>   Contains many pk_tickNum 
>   id | pk_tickNum | Status | time`
>
> `/*table two 'Order' 
>   Only One Order*/
>   id | pk_order_num | tickNum | taker`
>
> `/*table three 'Transaction' 
>   Many Transactions, Many Item_num, One location p/item*/
>   id | pk_transaction | tickNum | item_num | Location`

I have a statement that says...

```
Select 
ticket1.pk_tickNum,ticket1.status,ticket1.time,order.pk_order_num 
From 
Status ticket1 left join Status ticket2 
ON
(ticket1.pk_tickNum = ticket2.pk_tickNum AND ticket1.ID < ticket2.ID)
Inner Join
order
ticket1.pk_tickNum = order.tickNum
WHERE
(ticket2.ID IS NULL)
```

This will give me the most current status of the order....

Works perfectly!!! However, we have Bins, ie: Locations. and every order has multiple items...
As the item moves through the warehouse, every `location` is recorded. So for every `order`, there are multiple `items` and each `item` has a `location` to include the `'shipped'` `location` which marks the end.

If I run the above query to `left join` the third `Transaction` table I get as many entries as there are `item_num` on a single transaction. I don't need that!

All I am looking for is a single output for the current `status` of a ticket if **ALL** `items` on a ticket are **NOT** in `location='shipped'`

Edit -

## Content

Status

`id | pk_tickNum | Status |
1 | 123456 | Green | 
2 | 123457 | Blue | 
3 | 123456 | Yellow | 
4 | 123456 | Red | 
5 | 123457 | Green |`

Order

`id | pk_order_num | tickNum |
1 | 987654 | 123456
2 | 987656 | 123457`

Transaction

`id | pk_transaction | tickNum | item_num | Location
1 | 5555555555 | 123456 | Some   | Floor
2 | 5555555556 | 123456 | Thing  | Floor
3 | 5555555557 | 123456 | Smart  | Shipped
4 | 5555555558 | 123456 | or     | Shipped
5 | 5555555559 | 123457 | Really | Shipped
6 | 5555555560 | 123457 | Noth   | Shipped
7 | 5555555561 | 123457 | ing    | Shipped`

Output - 

`pk_order_num | pk_tickNum | Status |
987654 | 123456 | Red | 
/*987656 | 123457 | Green |*/ This should not show!`

Answer! - Posted By @Used_By_Already And sample code supplied [available at SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fda53/1)

Thank you!

Comment: sample output?   What should the status be if not all "shipped" PS for partially Shipped? CS for completly shipped?

Comment: use EXISTS ... there are plenty of articles  here

Comment: Using SQL-Server @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: As mentioned, you just need an exists clause. e.g. `AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Transaction] WHERE [Transaction].tickNum = ticket1.pk_tickNum and Location <> 'Shipped')`

Comment: Please tell me you don't have a table called "order" and that it is "orders" or something that isn't a SQL keyword. Please oh please don't call a table "order"! and not "transaction" but "transactions", oh no....

Comment: LOL no I just used these to publicly state my issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really do hope you don't have tables called "order" and "transaction", if you do make sure they are contained in [] or "" for my sanity I used "s" on the end of those names.

To achieve this result ([available at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef9f9/1)):

```
| pk_order_num | tickNum | Status |
|--------------|---------|--------|
|       987654 |  123456 |    Red |
```

I have assumed that the "most recent" row in the status table is determined by the reverse order of the ID column (this isn't a great way to do it, but that's the only available columns to work with). A better column would be a "last updated" datetime value to base this on, perhaps that is the column [time] in that table, but no data was supplied for it.

```
SELECT
        o.pk_order_num
      , o.tickNum
      , s.Status
FROM [orders] o
INNER JOIN (
            select pk_tickNum, Status
                 , row_number() over(partition by pk_tickNum
                                     order by id desc) rn
            from status 
           ) s ON o.ticknum = s.pk_tickNum and s.rn = 1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
                ticknum
        FROM [transactions]
        GROUP BY ticknum
        HAVING COUNT(*) <> SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'shipped' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ) t ON s.pk_tickNum = t.ticknum
;
```

Also note that the final subquery using the `having clause` determines if all details in the transactions have been shipped or not. Only orders with unshipped transactions will be returned by that subquery.

Comment: WoW! this worked perfectly! I added some extra columns to the fiddle to verify! - [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fda53/1) Still worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  s.pk_tickNum, s.status, s.time, o.pk_order_num 
From Status s
-- actually this join already multiplies rows: ticket 123456 has more than one record in Status table in your sample data
Inner Join order o ON s.pk_tickNum = o.tickNum
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    -- why is it named `pk_tickNum` if this is not a PK?
    SELECT 1 FROM Status ticket2 
    WHERE s.pk_tickNum = ticket2.pk_tickNum AND s.ID < ticket2.ID
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    -- might catch "empty orders" if any
    SELECT 1 FROM Transaction t
    WHERE t.tickNum = s.pk_tickNum 
      and t.Location = 'shipped'
  )
```

Note, output from your sample data would be empty, because ticket 123456 has two items with location 'shipped' which violates conditions you described.

Comment: That's just it though, not `All` items are in `'shipped'`

Comment: I realize I should have used better keywords in my example. The tables are really well described.